# Texture image displaying properly on all faces of mesh

Tags: texturing, image, pbr

I have a mesh with 3 faces and I want all the faces to have the same texture, after seeing the result I tried to mess with the normals so all faces would face the same direction but that didn't work.

I am not sure what to look for and when searching "how to add a texture to two faces" all I find is "how to add two textures to one face".

To apply this texture I used the default *node wrangler* <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> shortcut to select all my texture files.

[image: Example]

Comment: I'm quite sure the Shift+Ctrl+T shortcut sets up the material so that it uses the UV map for the textures. Is the object properly UV unwrapped?

Comment: I am not experienced with UV wraps but yes its using UV on the `texture coordinate` node. I started with a cube but then I extruded a side then the other, and in the end I decided to do it as a plane so I deleted the other faces.. hope this makes sense.

Comment: You may be using the UV output from the Texture coordinate node but did you actually UV unwrap your object first? If you want all 3 faces to have the same texture layout and size you might consider Marking a Seam round each face before unwrapping. Then you can place and rotate the image on each face in the UV editor individually.

Comment: I see, thanks but I if there is a procedural way I would rather prefer than *unwrap*,
I am pretty sure its possible just dont know how I got there in the past.

Comment: I guess you'd have to use Geometry nodes (if it's even possible using them) but I'm not familiar with them I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advices on the comments but turns out for my case changing from `UV` to `Generated` solved the issue like a charm, even better than UV due to scales.

[image: Example]